# Changing a font size in the library graphdracula

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc4 application, in which i'd like to add a treeview . So i used this Jquery library : [graphdracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Scripts/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Scripts/dracula_graffle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Scripts/dracula_graph.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Scripts/dracula_algorithms.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
            var width = $(document).width() -500;
            var height = $(document).height();
            var g = new Graph();
            g.edgeFactory.template.style.directed = true;

           @for(int i =0;i < @Model[1].Count; i+=2){
              @: g.addEdge("@Html.Raw(@Model[1][i])","@Html.Raw(@Model[1][i+1])");

           }
            var layouter = new Graph.Layout.Ordered(g, topological_sort(g));
            var renderer = new Graph.Renderer.Raphael('canvas', g, width, height);

            });
       </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="canvas"></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

the result is :

[image: img]

i need to modify the font-size of the titles of the edges to 18px , i can't find the snippet to modify the tag's value.

How can i , so, modify the code ? Where can i find the target code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a custom node render function as described in [the documentation](http://www.graphdracula.net/documentation/).

Here's the important code from my local test page:

```
var g = new Graph();

var render = function(r, n) {
    var color = Raphael.getColor();
    var set = r.set().
        push(r.ellipse(n.point[0], n.point[1], 30, 20).attr({fill: color, stroke: color, "stroke-width": 2})).
        push(r.text(n.point[0], n.point[1] + 30, n.label || n.id).attr({"font-size": "18px"}));
    return set;
};

/* add a simple node */
g.addNode("strawberry", { render : render });
g.addNode("cherry", { render : render });
```